# gr-osmosdr: crashed while loading 'osmosdr_sink' 'osmosdr_source' 'rtlsdr_source'

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I installed the gnuradio(3.7.9.2) from source, that is OK, and installed the [rtl-sdr](http://sdr.osmocom.org/trac/wiki/rtl-sdr) and [gr-osmosdr](http://sdr.osmocom.org/trac/wiki/GrOsmoSDR) from source. The rtl-sdr is OK. When I run the `cmake ../` for gr-osmosdr, it outputs like this:

```
-- ######################################################
-- # Gnuradio enabled components                         
-- ######################################################
--   * Python support
--   * Osmocom IQ Imbalance Correction
--   * FUNcube Dongle Pro+
--   * IQ File Source & Sink
--   * Osmocom RTLSDR
--   * RTLSDR TCP Client
--   * Ettus USRP Devices
--   * RFSPACE Receivers
--   * Red Pitaya SDR
-- 
-- ######################################################
-- # Gnuradio disabled components                        
-- ######################################################
--   * sysmocom OsmoSDR
--   * FUNcube Dongle
--   * Osmocom MiriSDR
--   * HackRF & rad1o Badge
--   * nuand bladeRF
--   * AIRSPY Receiver
--   * SoapySDR support
-- 
-- Building for version: v0.1.4-72-g164a09fc / 0.1.5git
-- Using install prefix: /usr/local
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/wrsadmin/gr-osmosdr/builddir
```

and I run those:

```
make
sudo make install
```

everything is OK. When I run `gnuradio-companion` in the CLI, it outputs:

```
Warning: restarting the docstring loader (crashed while loading 'osmosdr_sink')
Warning: restarting the docstring loader (crashed while loading 'osmosdr_source')
Warning: restarting the docstring loader (crashed while loading 'rtlsdr_source')
```

When I drag the RTL-SDR source to the flowgraph, it outputs:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and exit.

**Why the gr-osmosdr broken the gnuradio-companion?**

Comment: hi, there's literally thousands of things that can lead to a segfault. Knowing your other question: Are you sure you have linked gr-osmosdr against the GNU Radio you're currently using, ie. have you updated GNU radio after building/installing gr-osmosdr?

Comment: I am sure I installed the GNU radio(3.7.9.2) first, and building/installing gr-osmosdr later and didn't updated GNU radio.

Comment: How did you install GNU Radio?

Comment: So we have to narrow this down. We'll need you to do two things:
1. try whether importing gr-osmosdr in python works at all – open a `python` shell, and execute `import osmosdr`. What happens?

Comment: 2. if that crashes, we'll need you to supply a debugger's *backtrace*.

Comment: Yes, when I run `import osmosdr` it outputs `"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"` and exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Marcus, I sloved it by `git reset --hard b7da9af4f229a213a225318656734e22dc068b02` for my gnuradio, the commit said that "Finalize release notes for v3.7.9.2"

Comment: and then you recompiled GNU Radio, installed it, then recompiled gr-osmosdr and installed it?

Comment: Yes, as your said.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this problem because I updated a few hours ago. What I have found, though not solved, is my OOM blocks are installed with python3.5 but gnuradio-companion cannot load them because it was running under python2.7 (i.e., the symlink for "python2").

dennisg@Tori-Radio:~/gr-acars-pen/lib$ python2.7
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import acars
> > >       Segmentation fault (core dumped)

dennisg@Tori-Radio:~/gr-acars-pen/lib$ python3.5
Python 3.5.1+ (default, Mar 30 2016, 22:46:26) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160330] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import acars
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/acars/**init**.py", line 34, in 
> > >           from IntruderPy import IntruderPy
> > >       ImportError: No module named 'IntruderPy'